# Problems rotating a model 'compas correct'

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation

The problem that I am having is as follows.
When I rotate my spaceship up (pitch) and rotate it at a full 90 degrees in the pitch, it stands up straight, and then try to rotate it again on the y-axis the model now rotates in the same fashion as a roll in the starting position.

Now my question, how can I fix this? How can I make sure my model always rolls when I want it to roll, always pitch when I want it to pitch, etc. Instead of what it does now.

I'm using c++ and opengl.

Comment: Sounds like [gimbal lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock#Loss_of_a_degree_of_freedom_with_Euler_angles). Use [quaternions](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL:Tutorials:Using_Quaternions_to_represent_rotation) to manage your rotations.

Comment: You have encountered gimble lock. I suggest looking at quaternions. I don't have much experience and will be of little help, but I know they solve the gimble lock issue. http://www.flipcode.com/documents/matrfaq.html

Comment: Thank you, both of you this indeed appears to be the problem.
So does this mean I need to go around the normal rotations of opengl and make my own?
So no more glRotatef(mRotation.x, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); But my own entire fix?

Comment: Correct.  Most quaternion systems can [spit out](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL%3aTutorials%3aUsing_Quaternions_to_represent_rotation#Quaternion_to_Matrix) a `glMultMatrix()`-compatible matrix that you can substitute in where your `glRotatef()`s were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been pointed out already, you're seeing [Gimbal Lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock) as a result of the way you're using Euler angles to perform rotations.

Quaternions are not the only solution, however. You can instead construct a 4x4 matrix to represent an object's current orientation, and apply *relative* rotations to it each time you change facing. It isn't perfect, as you need to keep track of 16 values per object instead of 4 for a quaternion, and in order to deal with floating point rounding errors you'll need to periodically normalise things so your orientation matrix doesn't become a skew transform. On the other hand, it is conceptually simple and pretty quick to put together.